# How can I make a browser record the click like Facebook does?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, client-side

This is my current project. I need to record the current state of an `<a>` and I get it with PHP, I must be missing something. I have tried to follow the `.on()` example, but the problem is that when I use it, it is not capturing the `click` event.

Can someone help please?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="current" name="text1">a</a>
<a href="#" id="current" name="text2">b</a>
<a href="#" id="current" name="text3">c</a>
<a href="#" id="current" name="text4">d</a>
```

Comment: Your code works as it is (although it doesn't make sense, since all the `a` elements have the same id "current")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the attribute by jQuery

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

JS :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() { 
    alert(id); 
});
```